# Maps Plugin to use for Xamarin Forms if any

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to figure out a good plugin to use, where I can load a map on the app and has clustering and custom pins enabled into it. I have tried 2 different options and they all miss the mark, I then have to do custom rendering which I end up breaking something in the plugin.
Plugins I have used

- [TK.CustomMap](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) (Works but there are a lot of bugs in this plugin, and these bugs seem to appear when `IsClusteringEnabled` is `True`. Also it doesn't seem to be a lot of interaction from the author. )
- Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps with Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering - (works but is slower than TK.CustomMaps for the rendering of pins. Also the clustering does not work as expected. It clusters in static positions and so like if pins are located in Santa Monica but the cluster is already created in Anaheim, all the pins will get pulled to Santa Monica, which looks weird from a user perspective.)

TKCustom maps works better overall but those bugs are very tedious and some of the workarounds are not longer working.

Is the better option or should I just use Xamarin.Forms.Maps and render all custom functions since Xamarin Maps seems to not include a lot of these?

Comment: You may use Open Street map. https://github.com/charlenni/Mapsui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a lot more plugins that might have worked but I ultimately ended up using custom controls and renderers to get what I wanted. It was simple enough for me to implement since what I wanted was not very complicated.
I did however find some very helpful links. Some of these are standard but it helped me understand different parts that I could implement to get all the specific actions and designs I needed.

- [New Features in MapKit on iOS 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios11/mapkit#clustering)
- [Customizing a Map Pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin)
- [Xamarin.Forms Map Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map)
- [XAMARIN.ANDROID – GROUPING GOOGLE MAP MARKERS WITH “CLUSTERING”](https://www.maximeesprit.com/en/xamarin-android-grouping-google-map-markers-with-clustering/)